# A for loop using an array does not return the expected number

Tags: arrays, for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5

If you add the code below to the chart, it will count the 7 items that are set to true by default in the input, and 7 should be displayed in the tablecell.
However, tablecell displays 5 or 6 digit numbers.
The numbers seem to change depending on the brand and the current close value.
How can I get the bool value aggregate I'm expecting?

```
//@version=5
indicator("test", overlay = true)
var int maxPos = 20

pL01_S = input.bool(true,  title="long pos 01", inline="L01-1", display=display.none)
pL02_S = input.bool(true,  title="long pos 02", inline="L02-1", display=display.none)
pL03_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 03", inline="L03-1", display=display.none)
pL04_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 04", inline="L04-1", display=display.none)
pL05_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 05", inline="L05-1", display=display.none)
pL06_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 06", inline="L06-1", display=display.none)
pL07_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 07", inline="L07-1", display=display.none)
pL08_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 08", inline="L08-1", display=display.none)
pL09_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 09", inline="L09-1", display=display.none)
pL10_S = input.bool(false,  title="long pos 10", inline="L10-1", display=display.none)
pS01_S = input.bool(true,  title="Short pos 01", inline="S01-1", display=display.none)
pS02_S = input.bool(true,  title="Short pos 02", inline="S02-1", display=display.none)
pS03_S = input.bool(true,  title="Short pos 03", inline="S03-1", display=display.none)
pS04_S = input.bool(true,  title="Short pos 04", inline="S04-1", display=display.none)
pS05_S = input.bool(true,  title="Short pos 05", inline="S05-1", display=display.none)
pS06_S = input.bool(false,  title="Short pos 06", inline="S06-1", display=display.none)
pS07_S = input.bool(false,  title="Short pos 07", inline="S07-1", display=display.none)
pS08_S = input.bool(false,  title="Short pos 08", inline="S08-1", display=display.none)
pS09_S = input.bool(false,  title="Short pos 09", inline="S09-1", display=display.none)
pS10_S = input.bool(false,  title="Short pos 10", inline="S10-1", display=display.none)

pShow = array.new_bool(20, false)
array.set(pShow, 0, pL01_S)
array.set(pShow, 1, pL02_S)
array.set(pShow, 2, pL03_S)
array.set(pShow, 3, pL04_S)
array.set(pShow, 4, pL05_S)
array.set(pShow, 5, pL06_S)
array.set(pShow, 6, pL07_S)
array.set(pShow, 7, pL08_S)
array.set(pShow, 8, pL09_S)
array.set(pShow, 9, pL10_S)
array.set(pShow, 10, pS01_S)
array.set(pShow, 11, pS02_S)
array.set(pShow, 12, pS03_S)
array.set(pShow, 13, pS04_S)
array.set(pShow, 14, pS05_S)
array.set(pShow, 15, pS06_S)
array.set(pShow, 16, pS07_S)
array.set(pShow, 17, pS08_S)
array.set(pShow, 18, pS09_S)
array.set(pShow, 19, pS10_S)

var int tabNo = 0
for i = 0 to maxPos - 1
    if array.get(pShow, i)
        tabNo := tabNo + 1
pTab = table.new(position.top_center, 4, 1, bgcolor=color.new(color.black, 56), frame_color=color.new(color.blue, 80), frame_width=1, border_color=color.new(color.blue, 80),border_width=1)
table.cell(pTab, 0, 0, text=str.tostring(tabNo))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the loop on every bar and because your `tabNo` is initialized using using `var` it never resets.

You can run your loop using a if `barstate.islast` and reset `tabNo` at every new bar or remove the `var`.

```
tabNo = 0
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to maxPos - 1
        if array.get(pShow, i)
            tabNo := tabNo + 1
```